# Correct usage of “concededly”

Tags: word-usage

The only example I could find of this words usage is

> They concededly ignored the historical record and made assumptions about jury behavior that have been called into question by more recent research.

Somebody is trying to convince me that this usage is correct.

> “Yes” Jamie says concededly.

I’m trying to say that this usage is correct.

> “Yes” Jamie conceded.

Are they both correct or is one incorrect?

Comment: Good question. I don't know that I've ever seen the word concededly used in writing and I think it's worth suggesting there's likely good reason to avoid it. To me the former suggests conveyance of emotion by Jamie, while the latter simply indicates that he conceded. It would seem to me that the emotion commonly associated with saying something concededly is reluctance, though I'm not sure why I think that because to concede doesn't imply that, excepting in a game of chess maybe.

Comment: Consider that most readers would assume that you misspelled "conceitedly".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to dictionaries such as the Oxford English Dictionary and [Burton's Legal Thesaurus (via TFD)](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/concededly), "concededly" means "admittedly". And it makes no sense to say '“Yes” Jamie says admittedly.'

It is correct to say '“Yes” Jamie conceded.' This specific usage is listed in several dictionaries, such as [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conceded). (Some people, however, would probably disapprove of this usage for [stylistic reasons](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/3163).)

Comment: Absolutely right to flag _concededly_ as a legalism. Here's a lovely example from [some old NY court reports](https://www.google.com/search?q=concededly&tbm=bks&ei=dw-dW8rdGMyUgQazi4DQBg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1170&bih=790&dpr=1.75) (1918): _Concededly in the case at bar there is an executory agreement for the purchase and sale of stock. Concededly this agreement was not in fact carried out by the parties thereto. Concededly there was no actual delivery ._ This example shows how it is _generally_ used: for points which have been conceded by both sides and which are not at issue. It's an awful word.